# How to generate a random SKSpriteNode based on four possible values

Tags: ios, swift, sprite, skspritenode

To generate an image I have written the following function. However, I want that function to able to generate one of four possible images, instead of the same image every time. Right now it generates the "Top Side" image every time, but I want it to randomly choose one of the four images I have to generate.

```
func spawnBrick()  {
    let Brick = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Top Side")
    Brick.size = CGSize(width: 130, height: 100)
    Brick.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.maxY - Brick.size.width)
    addChild(Brick)

}
enum brickType: UInt {
    case brickTop = 1
    case brickLeft = 2
    case brickRight = 3
    case brickBottom = 4

}


let brickTop = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Top Side")

let brickLeft = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Left Side")


let brickRight = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Right Side")


let brickBottom = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Bottom Side")
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift array has a method called randomElement that will give you an optional element from the array (not its optional because the array could be empty)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994747-randomelement

```
func spawnBrick()  {
    let Brick = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: ["Top Side","Left Side","Right Side","Bottom Side"].randomElement()!)
    Brick.size = CGSize(width: 130, height: 100)
    Brick.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.maxY - Brick.size.width)
    addChild(Brick)

}
```